# How to set time with Current Time Service ( CTS ) on the Bluetooth Low Energy ( BLE ) device with Cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, time, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using cordova-plugin-ble-central ( https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central ) to read data from BLE broadcast frame. The time in Epoch Time standard is stored in that broadcast frame in Manufacturer Data and also few more data.

How I can set that time with Current Time Service base on app time ?

When the BLE device is booted it starts with the date 01.01.1970 00:00:00 and I want change this date to current date. If I understand correctly I have to get current time in Epoch Time and then with Current Time Service standard "send/write" to BLE device but I do not know how.

I will be very grateful for any help or suggestions.

Comment: I would suggest learning how to do this with a generic Bluetooth Low Energy scanning and exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile). People often find it easier to implement once they know the steps, UUIDs etc required.

Comment: @ukBaz is there an easier way to share the CTS (Current Time Service) characteristics to the BLE device. Base on your suggestions in nRF Connect I have to create GATT server and create there Current Time Service then connect and bonded phone with BLE device but how to create GATTserver in Apach Cordova with javascript or what plugin do I need. I found something like this https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-peripheral. I will be grateful for any additional suggestions if you can help.

Comment: I have understood that you are trying to set the date and time on a BLE device which boots with the wrong value. You have not told us anything about that BLE device but my assumption was that the BLE device already offers GATT services and characteristics to set the time and date and that was why you were trying to create a BLE Central. Without knowing anything about the device it is difficult to advise. By using nRF Connect to find out more information about the BLE device (and even set the value) then it is easier to understand how to create the required BLE Central to set the time and date.